# change the behavior of "if" statement in perl a little bit

Tags: arrays, perl

I inherit lots of code like the following

```
if (func1()) { .... }
```

The "func1()" may return a scalar, an array or an reference to array.  I would like the evaluation of "if" in the above as the following:

- when func1() returns an array, it should evaluate to be true if there is at least one element in the array
- when func1() returns a reference to an array, it should evaluate to be true if there is at least one element in the array being referenced.
- when func1() returns a scalar, just evaluate it as normal

I know I can do something like the following

```
@a = func1();
if (!defined $a[0]) {
    #false
} elsif (ref($a[0] eq "ARRAY") {
    if (scalar(@{$a[0]})) {
        #true
    } else {
        #false
    }
} elsif ($a[0]) {
    #true
} else {
    #false
}
```

But this is tedious and there are many such occurance of `if (func1())...`.  Wonder if there is a simple way to make the perl "if" statement behave as I want.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

Thanks to @ikegami 's question, I realized my real issue is the following (see the comment in the following, reproduced here to make it easy to read)

`funcX()` will return a reference to a list. The current behavior  of `if` is that it will always evaluate to be true regardless of whether the referenced list is empty or not.   But I would like `if (funcX())` to evaluate to be false if the referenced list is empty and true otherwise.

Comment: Perhaps `func1` itself should be modified to return a boolean when called in scalar context. If you can't do that, consider a wrapper function to translate the result.

Comment: @Wumpus, thanks for pointing it out. Unfortunately in my situation, there are many functions like func1 ("func1" is just an example).  Would be great if I can change the behavior for "if" a little bit.

Comment: 1) It's impossible to return an array. Only a list of scalar can be returned by subs. In scalar context, that is further limited to exactly one scalar.

Comment: 2) Your spec is self-contradicting. A one element list (which you mistakenly call an array) should be considered true, and a single scalar should be checked for truth, yet there's no difference between the two.

Comment: @ikegami, thanks for the questions to clarify and the tip. Looked at it again, `funcX()` will return a reference to a list in the code.   I would like `if (funcX())` to evaluate to be false if the referenced list is empty and true otherwise.   But default behavior of `if` is so that `if (funcX())` will always evaluate to be true. I am going to update the question.

Comment: There's no such thing as a reference to a list. You've decided to break the only thing that made sense.

Comment: @codingFun `{ my $arr_ref = foo(); if (@$arr_ref) { ... } }`.

Comment: @ikegami, @a = (11,12,13) is a list,  $b = \@a is a reference to a list.

Comment: @Slade, thanks for the idea. I would have used it if there are a few occurrences of `if (funcX(...)) ...`.

Comment: @codingFun, No, `@a = (11,12,13)` is *code* that assigns scalars to an array. `$b` holds a reference to an *array*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sub check($) {
   return undef if !$_[0];
   return undef if ( ref($_[0]) || '' ) eq 'ARRAY' && !@{ $_[0] };
   return 1;
}

if (check(func1()) {
   ...
}
```

Like in your original code (and contrary to what you said), `func1` must return a scalar. `check` return false if the scalar is false, false if the scalar is a reference to an empty array, and true otherwise. (Just like your overly complex check that doesn't compile and can throws a warning when `func1` returns a true value that's not an reference.)

Comment: By the way, there are too many occurrences of `if (funcX()) ...`, would like a "magic" way to change behavior of "if" to achieve this :-)

Comment: Really?!? Use a regex substitution!

Comment: Couldn't use regex for a couple of reasons. One of them is, `funcX(...)`  has complex parameters and regex may not catch it.  Seems that in theory perl intepreter can support this:  if the value is  reference to a list, then use the size of the referenced list as a way to make decision.

Comment: Don't need to match the parameters `s/if \(\K/check /g`

Comment: Again, there's no such thing as a reference to a list. The code I posted does check the size of referenced arrays, though

Comment: `funcX(...)` can be complex, for example,  `funcX(3, funcY(3+4, ...), ...)`, using regex to insert `check` function is going to be tough to get all occurrences right.

Comment: agree that your function basically will enhance the `if` condition as I would like. However, inserting a function is tough, so a way to augment the `if` in the interpreter would be great.

Comment: Re "`funcX(...)` can be complex", so? Re "function is going to be tough to get all occurrences right", Not at all. Again, use `s/if \(\K/check /g`. Re "However, inserting a function is tough", No, it's easy. I even wrote the code for you. Re "so a way to augment the if in the interpreter would be great." It's possible to override keywords. See Syntax::Feature::Loop, Syntax::Feature::Void, Syntax::Feature::QwComments. But that uses custom parsers and opcode tree manipulations. That's nuclear physics if `s/if \(\K/check /g` is grade 1 addition skills.

Comment: thanks for the discussion. I will accept your answer.  It really helped!